# ENOTFOUND error when call external api endpoint from Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Please provide any suggestions on what needs to be changed with the below code to execute it from Lambda function. It works perfectly fine locally however when executed in Lambda get the following error -
{"errno":"ENOTFOUND","code":"ENOTFOUND","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"https://api.taggun.io"}",

```
const API_KEY = 'XXxxxxxxxxxxxxxXXX';
/*const fs = require("fs");
const rp = require("request");*/
const https= require('https');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = function(event,context,callback){
    var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    var srcKey    = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
    var params = {Bucket: srcBucket, Key: srcKey};
    var origimage = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();

    const formData = JSON.stringify({
    file: {
      value: origimage,
      }
    });
    const options = {
    hostname: "https://api.taggun.io",
    path: "/api/receipt/v1/simple/file",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {apikey:API_KEY}
  };
  const req = https.request(options,
      (res) => res.on("data", () => callback(null, "OK")));
  req.on("error", (error) => callback(JSON.stringify(error)));
  req.write(formData);
  req.end();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason it may work locally and not when deployed could be a matter of network connectivity. If the endpoint you are trying to hit is on a private network, you may need to ensure that your lambda is deployed into a vpc subnet which has network connectivity to that private network. If that is the case, these [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html) show the permissions and process for deploying a lambda into a subnet.

Answer (score 0):

It mean your lambda cannot reach `https://api.taggun.io`

Is your lambda in a VPC ? Assert it has an internet connection